# TCP server, recv() принимает ненужные запросы

Tags: linux, c, http, tcp

Есть TCP сервер, который обрабатывает запросы клиента. Клиент может послать серверу данные, например строку **"Username 340 40 03:15"**. Сервер получит эту строку с помощью `recv()` и запишет содержимое полученного буфера в обычный файл. В этом файле накапливаются подобные строки и клиент при надобности сможет запросить содержимое этого файла с сервера.

Сервер находится в состоянии `listen()` *24/7* и иногда, откуда-то, приходят совсем иные запросы. И я могу наблюдать, что `recv()` буфер, а затем и сам файл содержит подобные записи:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
TE: deflate,gzip;q=0.3
Connection: TE, close
```

```
HTTP ... Keep-alive ...
```

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: [server-ip]:[port]
User-Agent: Wget/1.21.2
```

Видимо кто - то посылает запросы с помощью `curl` / `wget` и подобных утилит

Проблема в том, что IP сервера и его порт виден в коде данного проекта и любой проходимец может посылать такие запросы серверу, а программный код успешно их обработает и запишет куда не нужно, это загрязняет файл и затем его приходится чистить в ручную. Подскажите как можно этого избежать ?

Я сам попробовал с терминала послать подобные:

```
curl [ip]:[port]
```

в выводе вижу

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

а на стороне сервера:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: [ip]:[port]
User-Agent: curl/7.79.1
```

Comment: Добавить хоть какую-нибудь аутентификацию и проверять, что клиент настоящий, наверное?

Comment: ну или как минимум проверять, что строка соответствует минимально ожидаемому формату… это, правда, конечно, ни как не остановит злоумышленника от посылки своих квазикорректных данных…

Comment: - "IP сервера и его порт виден в коде данного проекта и любой проходимец может" - Но ведь IP и порт гуглы знает весь мир и что? Причём тут исходные тексты? **Любой** сервер должен выставлять свой IP и порт на всеобщее обозрение, иначе с ним будет невозможно соединиться.  Если Вам нужно добиться, что бы сервер принимал запросы только от "хороших" клиентов, ну так сделайте на сервере "белый список" и всех остальных просто отбрасывайте.

Comment: у меня была проблема, как у автора вопроса. При чем ввод обрабатывался отдельной либой,  куда вставить свои проверки было накладно. Решилось тем, что после подключения я читал первые байты через revc(..., MSG_PEEK), который читает данные, но не забирает их с буфера (и последующий recv их снова прочитает). и по прочитанному буферу делал проверки.  Мне оказалось достаточно проверять первый байт и отсекать почти всех левых.

Comment: всем спасибо за советы / ответы,
сделал выводы

Comment: я добавлял 2 символа в начало, например, "!@"